# ajax receive no respond from file

Tags: php, jquery

I use this ajax code to sumbit data to a file (refer below)

```
$(".editpost").submit(function (e) {
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax({
        url: formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data: postData,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (($.trim(data) == "success")) {

            } else {

            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        }
    });

    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
});
```

and the submitted data will be process through a switch statement (refer below)

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['jkey'])){
    $jkey = $_POST['jkey'];
    switch ($jkey)
    {
    case "jsave":
        echo "save is working";
    break;
    case "jadd":
        echo "add working";
    break;
    default:
        echo "Shall not waste time, creature!";
    }
}
?>
```

and i have this form that binds with the ajax data submit function

```
<form action="processor.php" method="post" class="editpost">
    <input type="hidden" name="jkey" value="jsave" />
    <input type="text" name="inputt" value="input sample" />
    <textarea name="textareaa">sample content</textarea>
    <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

as you can see base from the above codes, the ajax function firstly, get all the value from all the fields on the form (.editpost) and store it on postData variable and also get the file where all the data will be sent and then store it on a variable named formURL. In the processor.php, the post request jkey is stored on a variable jkey and then match the value to cases on the switch statement and if its match it then send back the specified content base on match case, for example since the value of the post request jkey is jsave then send back "save is working" from jsave case on the switch statement and when the ajax function receive respond, it will then alert the data received from the processor.php BUT ITS NOT WORKING, INSTEAD I receive a empty alert box or sometimes a alert box contains several codes of a page.

anyone who have ideas, recommendations and suggestions to make this work? thanks in advance.

Comment: <button>submit</submit> ???

Comment: my bad, just some wrong typo, it should be </button>. Post updated :)

Comment: try var_dump($_POST); before the if condition to see what all is coming in $_POST

Answer (score 0):

you are using class name of form to submit event. Instead use input button onclick function to  handle click event.